# Get Word Document indent

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I'm using Interop.Word for my app. So, my question is how can i get the right indent value?

I tried `WordDocument.Paragraphs.RightIndent` but it returns number of points (**99999** something like that). I dont understand where does this value come from.

Or maybe is there any easier way to programmatically put some symbols till the end of the paragraph?[image]

Comment: Your problem statement is unclear. Do you need to know the indentation of each paragraph *from the margin*? Or are you looking for the margin settings? And the reason you get back 99999 is because you're querying the entire Paragraphs collection of the document and at least one of them has a different setting than the others.... 999999 = "undefined".

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, i want to know the indentation of each paragraph from the margin

Comment: foreach Word.Paragraph para in WordDocument.Paragraphs { para.RightIndent; } doesn't work for you?

Comment: And be careful: with your edit (which I just saw) your question is in danger of being "too broad". You need to ask exactly what it is you want to know...

Comment: Are you all set, now?